# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar de blog.php?id=122 a bienvenidos-a-mi-blog en mi web?

Tags: php

Actualmente me encuentro trabajando en un blog con PHP y MySQL y me surgió una duda que no sé cómo aplicar.

Resulta que al enviar los enlaces con la etiqueta `<a>` mi página se muestra como:

```
http://localhost/test.php?id=122
```

Pero me gustaría que el enlace se mostrara con el título de la publicación, por ejemplo:

```
http://localhost/bienvenidos-a-mi-blog
```

¿Alguien podría explicarme cómo puedo hacerlo?

Este es mi archivo `index.php`:

```
          <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
        
          <div class="blog-post">
            <a class="boton-blog" href="blog.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']?>">
            </div>

          
         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Puedes buscar una de las muchas opciones para implementar URL seo-friendly en PHP. Más allá de ésto, la pregunta es muy amplia para el formato del sitio.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar sistema operativo, servidor HTTP y método de ejecución de PHP? Lo más común en principiantes suele ser una pila WAMP (Windows, Apache, PHP y MySQL), en un VPS lo más común es un LAMP (Linux, Apache, PHP y MySQL) pero también podrías usar un servidor IIS, Nginx + PHP-FPM, etc. Necesitaría toda la información que puedas proporcionarme porque el método varía dependiendo sobre todo del servidor HTTP que uses.